# Why is the formal parameter of C + + overloaded extraction operator in the form of reference?

Tags: c++

for example，

```
istream &operator(istream &input,PhoneNumber &number)
```

(the PhoneNumber is a class made by me)

I'm very thankful if you can reply to me

Comment: Because the stream state will change, and streams can't be copied.

Comment: what else should it be ?

Comment: typo? did you mean `operator>>` ?

Comment: Because that's how overloaded operators work. If you have a binary expression in the form `a op b` then the compiler will call the overloaded function as either `a.operator op(b)` or `operator op(a, b)`. Since you can't overload the "extraction" operator `>>` as a member of the input stream object, the second variant have to be used. And as mentioned, the the input stream state is both modified as well as it can't be copied, so it must be passed by reference.

Comment: This is explained in any beginner level C++ book listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list). In particular, the first parameter is a reference because streams can't be copied.

Comment: The `number` parameter is a reference because the function is going to modify the object passed to it.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude 
 thanks! I get it(*^▽^*)

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ thanks! I get it(*^▽^*)